# AlertDialog is being launched twice on Android 4.0.3

Tags: android

My application has 1 main activity and 2 other activities.

Whenever I start any of them it is being launched twice on Android 4.0.3 however on 2.3.6 it's being launched once.

It doesn't apply for activity only, however, it applies for `AlertDialog`s.

I added `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in the manifest and it worked good for normal `Activitie`s, however, i'm not being able to do anything for the AlertDialog.

To note: I am using HoloeveryWhere and SherlockActionBar.

Comment: Post the relevant code. Or better yet, place a breakpoint near `show()` and see what presents the second dialog.

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. I was at uni.. :) how can I put a breakpoint?

Comment: Google for it. Eclipse is pretty well documented.